# Why is "body" being reset to zero?

Tags: java

My program draws a cootie monster (a body and a head) and the body HAS to be drawn before the head. But when I run the program, it says "Can't add body part!" when I type in 2 as the input (even when I already have the body drawn). NOTE: 1 as an input draws the body and 2 draws the head.

I've identified the problem already, but I'm not sure how to fix it. The problem is that head is being reset to 0 before it enters the "if (rollValue == 2)...". My program can draw the body, but after it finished drawing the body, my "body" variable seems to get set back to 0. Which is why my program isn't drawing the head. Any ideas on how to fix it so that my program doesn't reset "body" back to 0 after drawing the body?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Cootie
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      boolean done = false;

      while (!done)
      {
         Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("BODY PARTS:");
         System.out.println("1 = body");
         System.out.println("2 = head");
         System.out.println("3 = one leg");
         System.out.println("4 = one antenna");
         System.out.println("5 = one eye");
         System.out.println("6 = tail");
         System.out.println("What number did you roll?: ");
         int rollValue = scanner.nextInt();

         int body = 0;
         int head = 0;

         if (rollValue == 1)
         {
            if (body == 0)
            {
               body = 1;
            }
            else
            {
               System.out.println("Can't add body part!");
               System.out.println(" ");;
            }
         }
         else if (rollValue == 2)
         {
            if (body == 1 && head == 0)
            {
               head = 1;
            }
            else
            {
               System.out.println("Can't add body part!");
            }
         }
         else
         {
            System.out.println("Enter a valid input!");
         }
         if (body == 1)
         {
            System.out.println("------------------------------");
            System.out.println("You got the body!");
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.println("   [ ]");
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.println("   [ ]");
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.println("   [ ]");
            System.out.println(" ");
         }
         if (head == 1)
         {
            System.out.println("You got the head!");
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.println("  (    )");
         }
         if (body == 1 && head == 1)
         {
            System.out.println("Congratulations you have completed your cootie!");
            done = true;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Just a hunch -- maybe this is doing it: `int body = 0;`

Comment: Karen you always have the same problem. All your question you are adding additional unwanted statements in loop. :p

Comment: @wrongAnswer: Yeah, I'm doing this as practice. There's more to the program, but I just need some guidance on this part. :)

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/26186740/1085186 correct ans !

Comment: Thanks! :D I should've caught this, such an easy solution. Guess this is what happens when you've been looking at a bunch of code for too long. :P

Answer (score 4):

You've declared your `body` (and `head`) variables inside the `while` loop, so this will run each loop:

```
int body = 0;
int head = 0;
```

So every loop, these variables are reset to `0`.  To keep the values for different iterations, declare and initialize them before the `while` loop, so they're initialized to `0` only once.  (You can declare and initialize your `Scanner` before the loop begins also.)

```
int body = 0;
int head = 0;
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

while (!done)
{
   // Other code still the same
```

Comment: OH, didn't even realize they were declared in the while loop! I should've caught that, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is because you declare body and head to be WITHIN the while loop. To fix this, create the variables before the

```
while (!done)
```

iterates.

Comment: Haha! I can't believe I didn't catch that! Didn't even realize I declared those in the while loop. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your body and head variable is initialized inside the while loop that's why it is reset to zero every time. Just move out these variables from the while loop.

Initialize you variable inside the loop when you want to reset your variable value on each iteration or If you want to keep maintain you update value with in the loop than initialized those variable outside the loop.